# Access to document inside react-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Are there any best practices which explain how to bind events to document inside react components?

Is it normal to make following:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    color: "red",
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      this.setState();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color}}>
        hello, world!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it better to create own event-listener, and process all interaction inside (eg, call component's method )?

Comment: this should be fine.

Comment: Do not forget to remove listeners in componentWillUnmount method while removing the component